# Long Running PHP Script not fetching the data

Tags: php, linux, curl, background-process

I am using a `php` script for polling new articles for a post. I use CURL for fetching the new data. When I run the script(`main.php` as `./main.php`) in `apache` server, Its fetching the data at that time.

If I check the database after one day, its not updated. When I check the script, Its still running. Suggest me the good way to run the `PHP 24*7` time

Comment: Did you write anything yet?

Answer (score -2):

Suggestions:

- Make a service / daemon out of it.
- Insert logging into your code to trace what is happening (log4php comes to mind). This allows you to monitor (tail -f) what is happening in real time.
- Use [restartd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/restartd.8.html) to restart when php crashes on an error